# what is difference between these "new Date()"s?

Tags: javascript, date

```js
var today = new Date();
var endYear = new Date(1995, 11, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999); // Set day and month
endYear.setFullYear(today.getFullYear()); // Set year to this year
console.log("Version 1: end year full date is ", endYear);
var msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // Number of milliseconds per day
var daysLeft = (endYear.getTime() - today.getTime()) / msPerDay;
var daysLeft = Math.round(daysLeft); //returns days left in the year
console.log(daysLeft,endYear);

// when l write that code answer is 245.


var today = new Date();
var endYear = new Date(2021, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); // Set day and month
console.log("Version 2: end year full date is ", endYear);    
var msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // Number of milliseconds per day
var daysLeft = (endYear.getTime() - today.getTime()) / msPerDay;
var daysLeft = Math.round(daysLeft); //returns days left in the year
console.log(daysLeft,endYear);

// but when l add only 1 ms then answer returns like 244. but how is it possible? where has 1 day gone?
```

Comment: What does this print if you take out the Math.round?

Comment: 244.08811538194445 & 245.08149202546295

Comment: I added console.log of endyear so you can see the difference

Comment: one of you had written here that dates changes 1-31 range. l think he was right. but then why didn't console throw any error? (or does console always show errors?)

Comment: @NigarAliyeva because the Date constructor does not treat that as an error; it adjusts the date in order to make things make sense. Using 0 for the day-of-month is effectively the same as using the last day of the previous month.

Comment: @Pointy thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

That is the difference with the time you set.

To be clear,

first `endYear` will print `Thu Dec 31 2020 23:59:59`

second `endYear` will print `Thu Dec 31 2020 00:00:00`

That is the difference you see there.

I will post the complete out put I received on console here as well.

```
Thu Dec 31 2020 23:59:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
245.0131708912037
245
Thu Dec 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
244.01317090277777
244
```

==================EDIT==================

`new  Date(2021, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` calculates this to Dec 31st because date is indexed from 1 and not zero. If that value is zero it computes it as the day before the 31st of December.

For example,

`new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))` will print out `Sat Jan 31 2021 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

and

`new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0))` will print out `Sat Jan 30 2021 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Comment: This is not the way it works for me. The first date (for me, given my local time zone) is about 5 AM on the morning of 1 Jan 2021. I suggest you actually try what you're claiming.

Comment: This is the output I got when I ran it in my cosole

Comment: mine is GMT+5:30

Comment: When I run the current version of the snippet, I get *much* different dates.

Comment: I updated my answer, my first answer was not explained well, sorry about that